Trouble with GoogleCredentials on Server
I’m facing an issue where my GoogleCredentials work perfectly fine on my local machine but don’t on the server. I’m using the following code:
InputStream credentialsStream = createJsonFile(keyFileStream);
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream)
.createScoped(
Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control")
);

Problem:
It works locally, but on the server, it doesn't work. It gets stuck at this step without any error message. Anyone else faced this issue or have any solutions?
Note:
I have tried running the code on my local machine, and it works perfectly fine, so I assume that the credential file and API scopes are correctly configured in my local environment.
